# How do you install subcommands?

Tags: go, darwin, subcommand

I am getting the following error message in Go v. 1.15.8 darwin/amd64

```
main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/google/subcommands" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/google/subcommands (from $GOROOT)
/Users/user1/go/src/github.com/google/subcommands (from $GOPATH)
```

The code in main.go looks like:

```
package main

import (
        "flag"
        "context"
        "os"

        "github.com/google/subcommands"
)
```

I know subcommands is located here: https://github.com/google/subcommands
with the git repo here: https://github.com/google/subcommands.git

But how do I install it?

When I do:

```
go get github.com/google/subcommands
```

I get the following error message:

```
# cd .; git clone -- https://github.com/google/subcommands /Users/user1/go/src/github.com/google/subcommands
Cloning into '/Users/user1/go/src/github.com/google/subcommands'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/google/subcommands/': Could not resolve host: github.com
package github.com/google/subcommands: exit status 128
```

When I open my web browser and go to: https://github.com/google/subcommands/ I can see the web page with no problems.  So why is the "go get" command having trouble with this?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? What is the output of `git config --global --get-regexp ".*proxy"` and what are the proxy settings in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of git config, you can also check your environment variable for `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY`

But more importantly, check if adding `GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org` could help (there are [other Go module proxies as well](https://arslan.io/2019/08/02/why-you-should-use-a-go-module-proxy/#how-to-use-a-go-module-proxy))

This could help getting modules from any provider, GitHub or others.